# angularfire .5 JWT token login doesn't work

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Ok.  Maybe its a doc issue but I am now trying to migrate from .4 to .5.  After having initial problems initializing $rootScope.fbAuth, it is now properly initialized.  $rootScope.fbAuth.user == null.   Using the same JWT that works in .4 never fulfills the login promise in .5.  Hence the .then never gets executed.  Here is the code:

```
         // Login now that we have a token
        $rootScope.fbAuth.$login(data['firebase']['access_token']).then(
            function(user){
                $log.log("Firebase Login Succeeded!");
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
                alert("Login Failure.  Unable to login to database(firebase)");
                fbDataFactory.ready.resolve(false);
            });
```

Comment: There was a bug where the promise wasn't resolved in the case of custom login, please update to the latest version on Github and test again (let us know if it still doesn't work!): https://github.com/firebase/angularFire

Comment: Thanks.  Are you going to update the cdn?

Comment: Ok.  That worked.  So far each step of this migration has failed.  Now the promise resolves but the $bind ( which I initiate after this promise is fulfilled ) does not.  Here is the code:        
           fbDataFactory.uid=user.id; 
           var refUsers = new Firebase(fbDataFactory.FBURL+'/users/'+fbDataFactory.uid);
                    $rootScope.fbUser = $firebase(refUsers);
                    $rootScope.fbUser.$bind($rootscope, "profile").then (function(d){ console.log("got here"); }); ...

Comment: Got it to return the promise from the bind but no data in variable that was supposed to be bound...I will investigate.

Comment: Ok - thanks! Yes, we'll be updating the CDN after bundling in a few more fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been remedied on GitHub.